# "перевтілитися" - якою конструкцією замінити?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Вислів "миттєве перевтілення" пасує до сенсів, пов’язаних із перевтіленням істот)) і не пасує до сенсів побутових. Перевтілення має конотацію "у що". "Миттєве перевтілення волосся" - у що? "Миттєве перевтілення шкіри" - у що? А треба сказати не у що, а всього лише "зробилося красившим".
Прошу допомогти відшукати притомний українськомовний вислів.

Comment: Бажано вказувати, чим не влаштовує наявний варіант. Запитання про переклад з інших мов не повинно передбачати знання нашими читачами цих інших мов. Якщо, натомість, ви своїми словами опишете іншомовний термін, то користувачі цього сайту, *маючи знання лише української* можуть надати відповідь.

Comment: Вислів "миттєве перевтілення" пасує до сенсів, пов'язаних із перевтіленням істот)) і не пасує до сенсів побутових. Перевтілення має конотацію "у що". "Миттєве перевтілення волосся" - у що? "Миттєве перевтілення шкіри" - у що? А треба сказати не у що, а всього лише "зробилося красившим". 
Відредагувати запитання?
Ось так добре?

Comment: @ОленаЛісовська, так, мені здається, тепер набагато краще. (Хоча російський варіант я б залишив теж: комусь це допоможе ще краще зрозуміти контекст, а комусь — знайти запитання пошуком; принаймні я б особисто залишив би, хоча, можливо, і не всі зі мною погодяться.)

Comment: перетворення? зміна?..

Comment: Наскільки я розумію англійський рекламний слоган "Instant hair transformation", можна серед перекладу пошукати синоніми: оновлення, покращення, відновлення, трансформування, вдосконалення...

Answer (score 1):

А як щодо словосполучення ***миттєва переміна*** (або *миттєві зміни*)? Приклад з літератури:

> Миттєва переміна, що сталася в ній, вразила мене не менше, ніж сама відповідь («Жінка в білому» Вілкі Коллінза в перекладі Олександра Мокровольського).

Є ще синоніми: *метаморфоза*, *переродження*, *перетворення*, *трансформація* — але з ними, мені здається, може бути та сама проблема, що й із *перевтіленням*: вони можуть натякати не просто на зміну, а на *докорінну* зміну, і в читача (слухача) може виникнути питання «а яка саме нова форма?» або ж просто відчуття невідповідності.

Хоча з усіма наведеними в цій відповіді варіантами (зокрема й *зміною*, *переміною*), мені здається, є проблема, що вони не дуже здатні *керувати* вточнюючими словами на зразок *волосся*, *шкіра* тощо. Але принаймні, мені здається, можливо опустити вточнююче слово в самому словосполученні й пояснити пізніше, щось на кшталт:

> Миттєва переміна (зміна, трансформація тощо): Ваше волосся буде (стане) неперевершене!

Comment: Я повторюю: йдеться про побутові речі. "Від цього шампуню ваше волосся переміниться"? Трансформується? Метаморфізується? Переродиться? Перетвориться? На що?)))
Волосся неперевершеним не буває.

Comment: @ОленаЛісовська, вибачте, я чомусь надто сконцентрувався на іменнику (забув про дієслова). А як щодо: «цей шампуть змінить ваше волосся»?

Comment: Тоді вже швидше щось типу "ваше волосся покращиться". 
Простіше заборонити застосовувати це кляте перевтілення у російськомовних варіантах текстів.

Comment: @ОленаЛісовська, може, ще так: «ваше волосся зміниться / стане іншим завдяки цьому шампуню». «Простіше заборонити застосовувати це кляте перевтілення у російськомовних варіантах текстів» — можливо, не знаю, Вам видніше (я можу лише констатувати, що мені більше якихось додаткових варіантів словосполучення в голову не приходить).